# I want to know what this line of code mean: /[a-zA-Z]/

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to  move the first character of a string to the end and then add "ay" to it, I tried to solve it but I couldn't and then I found this solution.
can you please explain to me the logic in this code.

```js
function pigIt(str){
  str = str.split(' ');
  for(let i = 0;i<str.length;i++){
    if(/[a-zA-Z]/.test(str[i])){
      str[i] = str[i].slice(1) + str[i][0] + 'ay';
    } 

  }
  return str.join(' ');
}
console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'));
```

Comment: It's a regex that matches lowercase a to z or uppercase A to Z. [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/BMVFy4/1).

Comment: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618)

Comment: That code doesn't generate proper Pig Latin.

Comment: This page on [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) has more information.